# How to calculate distances between countries from borders?

Tags: r, gis

I'm trying to fix the below code to calculate the distances between countries from the border. I believe, the code is not working because of packages being done in an old version of R and no longer supported. But this is just a guess.

The code I'm trying to get to work is [Closest distance between countries](https://egallic.fr/en/closest-distance-between-countries/) but it is using the package "maps" which doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
library(maps)
library(geosphere)
library(dplyr)

world.map <- map(database = "world", fill = TRUE)
```

Resulting error:

Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

Also, I was able to find the package [cepiigeodist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cepiigeodist/cepiigeodist.pdf)

Any idea how to fix this code? Or know of another package that will perform this task?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this is an angle to a solution

```
library( rnaturalearth )
library( rnaturalearthdata )
library( sf )

ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf" ) %>% 
  slice(1:5) %>% #only for first five countries
  st_distance( )

# Units: [m]
#            [,1]     [,2]    [,3]       [,4]    [,5]
# [1,]        0.0 12619446 9261566   958640.6 9022851
# [2,] 12619445.9        0 5860718 11647165.5 3538828
# [3,]  9261566.5  5860718       0  8615776.8 4938544
# [4,]   958640.6 11647165 8615777        0.0 8042914
# [5,]  9022851.4  3538828 4938544  8042913.9       0
```